# RSpec: undefined method `double' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fcc2f626d50>

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I wrote a simple test, as follows:

```
    require 'spec_helper.rb'

describe Channel do
  before(:each) do
    @channel = Channel.new
  end

  it "should get the true view count" do 
    upload_view_count = double('upload view count')
    upload_view_count.should_receive(:upload_num).and_return(16000666)
    @channel.upload_view_counts << upload_view_count
    @channel.save()
    @channel.true_all_time_views.should equal(16000666)
  end

  it "should get the true view count with multiple upload view counts" do
    upload_vc1 = double('uplaod view count 1')
    upload_vc1.should_receive(:created_at).and_return(Time.now())
    upload_vc1.should_receive(:upload_num).and_return(17666)
    upload_vc1.should_receive(:updated_at).and_return(Time.now())

    upload_vc2 = double('upload view count 2')
    upload_vc2.should_receive(:created_at).and_return(Time.now())
    upload_vc2.should_receive(:upload_num).and_return(17777)
    upload_vc2.should_receive(:updated_at).and_return(Time.now())

    @channel.upload_view_counts << upload_vc1
    @channel.upload_view_counts << upload_vc2
    @channel.save()
    @channel.true_all_time_views.should equal(17777)
  end




end
```

When I try to run this test, I get the following error:

> Failures:
>
> 1) Channel should get the true view count
>        Failure/Error: upload_view_count = double('upload view count')
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `double' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fcc2f66a8c0>
>        # ./spec/models/channel_spec.rb:9:in`block (2 levels) in '
>
> 2) Channel should get the true view count with multiple upload view
>   counts
>        Failure/Error: upload_vc1 = double('uplaod view count 1')
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `double' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fcc2f626d50>
>        # ./spec/models/channel_spec.rb:17:in`block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 37.68 seconds 5 examples, 2 failures, 3 pending
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/channel_spec.rb:8 # Channel should get the true
>   view count rspec ./spec/models/channel_spec.rb:16 # Channel should get
>   the true view count with multiple upload view counts

I've no idea why the double() method isn't working. I've searched high and low for this specific error and the closest thing I saw to something relevant was that require 'spec_helper.rb' was missing, but I have that line present. Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ended up being that the line config.mock_with :mocha was erroneously included in my spec_helper.rb file. Removing it did the trick.